# Rust inner loop causes double mutable borrow

Tags: rust

I am experimenting with building a small game prototype in ggez. I have created a struct called Engine, which I have added to the MainState. This struct contains some data, among which a vector of event listeners and a vector of events.

This Engine struct is incidentally passed to many functions, so that events (and other things) can be added.

I then have a double loop, going through each event and then going through each event-listener, to process them. But this very simple loop causes compilation issues.

```
  fn update(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult { 

        ...

        for event in &mut self.current_engine().events {
            for listener in &mut self.current_engine().system_event_listeners {
                // Would love to do some stuff here
            }
        }
```

The result is

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:81:34
   |
80 | for event in &mut self.current_engine().events {
   | ---------------------------------
   | | |
   | | first mutable borrow occurs here
   | first borrow later used here
81 | for listener in &mut self.current_engine().system_event_listeners {
   | ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I was able solve this problem by moving (popping) out all items of whichever vector I want to loop into a new vector. And then pushing them back in (because I want to re-use this list of listeners for every game-loop). But this is extremely convoluted, and I cannot imagine this is the proper way to do something as fundamental (and simple) was this.

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, or show this should be done instead.

Comment: Something like `let Engine { events, system_event_listeners } = self.current_engine();` may or may not work.

Comment: @Ry- This did work, after modifying the loop appropriately! What is the rational behind this, is it like borrowing all these variables at once? 

However, it does not completely solve my problem, because I want to pass the engine struct to my listener functions (for example: events can generate new events). And that still gives a compilation error.